# Ionic 5 : Remove page transition on Pop

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have been migrating my App from Ionic 3 to Ionic 5.
I am using Ionic NavController (which is a wrapper around Angular's router):

```
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
```

However, for some reason, I can't disable the animation on the pop. It doesn't take `NavigationOptions` as parameter. Here is what the doc says about it:

```
    /**
     * This methods goes back in the context of Ionic's stack navigation.
     *
     * It recursively finds the top active `ion-router-outlet` and calls `pop()`.
     * This is the recommended way to go back when you are using `ion-router-outlet`.
     */
    pop(): Promise<void>;
```

How can I disable the page transition animation for a pop() ?

Comment: I suppose you already read [migration ionic to 3.X to 4.X](https://ionicframework.com/docs/reference/migration#migrating-from-ionic-3-0-to-ionic-4-0) and after that, you also read [migration to 4.X to 5.X](https://ionicframework.com/docs/reference/migration#migrating-from-ionic-4-x-to-ionic-5-x). So I think you should need two steps, instead one. Because I think NavController is not longer used, and the ionic team have integrated with the official Angular Router

Comment: @JTejedor the documentation for v5.x is not entirely clear, but while Angular Router is fully supported, `NavController` exists and is not deprecated. It allows you to control animation and do things like remove all pages from the stack. These are features the Angular Router clearly can not support so I don't think it will be removed.

Comment: Maybe you are right. But under topic [Navigation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/reference/migration#navigation) in migration 3.X to 4.X, Ionic team explain how to perform any animation avoiding NavController using instead `ion-router-outlet`, quoting directly "To provide the platform-specific animations that users are used to, we have created `ion-router-outlet` for Angular Apps. This behaves in a similar manner to Angular's router-outlet but provides a stack-based navigation (tabs) and animations.". Anyway, it is just a suggestion, maybe still using `NavController` is a good idea.

Comment: i am obviously using ion-router-outlet, as stated, NavController is just a wrapper around the angular's router, it is not deprecated, and is part of the doc.